# Utilizing a Java Concurrent Utility from a Web App

Tags: java, design, packages

I have the following lines of code in my application:

```
return "Service is alive since: " + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(mxBean.getUptime()) + " minutes";
```

It uses the following package:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
```

My application is a web application. Does it means that I have something wrong logically if I use something from concurrent package at a web application?

Comment: As an old hardened C/C++ programmer I have to wonder at Java people who import code which has function names longer than the math required to do it inline. `ms/1000/60` isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Using TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(...) is fine as it doesn't actually invoke any threading behaviour (which would be incorrect in a Java EE container).  It's part of core Java, so no overheads.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any problem with this, and in fact using `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(...)` was the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/625624/421245) to the [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/625433/421245) that I found when googling "java convert milliseconds to minutes".

If you were in a constrained environment where you were worried about the size of your deployment, you might need to try cutting out any packages or jars that you don't need, but since java.util.concurrent is part of core Java, removing it would take some work.